# unable to smooth copy of object

Tags: normals

After copying the eye, the new object lost its smoothness.
Tried shading smooth, recalculating outside, smooth face, edge, and vertex.
[image]

Comment: is their any overlapping geometry?

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots file here: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/339937717343223809/990715861050458202/eye.blend

Comment: there's only one eye in your file and if I duplicate here it seems to work, could you please share the file with the 2 eyes?

Comment: @moonboots humm. ok, here you go: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/339937717343223809/990718609837944842/eye2.blend

Comment: it seems ok on my computer: https://zupimages.net/up/22/25/gigh.jpg

Comment: *visible confusion*

Comment: @moonboots Using blender 3.2 (Steam) what about you?

Comment: same, 3.2........

Comment: Try checking if resetting the normal data does anything. Its in the properties panel under *Object Data Properties> Geometry Data> Clear Custom Split Normals Data*

Comment: @Jakemoyo It is grayed out.